# jQuery optimization selector

Tags: jquery, optimization

I was wondering the other day when typing you selectors in jQuery would it make a difference in performance if you specify your selectors very specific or very loosely.

E.g

```
$('$myId .someElement')
```

Or

```
$('table#myId > tbody > tr > td > div.someElement');
```

Would the 2nd option be a lot quicker or would the difference be neglectable, say when doing `.each()` if you need to find the same element over and over.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go for:

```
$('.someElement', '#myId')
```

Since getElementById is the fastest selector operation, you are first filtering your content and then searching for the class. Also the fewer the selectors the faster the selections will be (depends if using *descendant* or *child* selectors - check comments!) .
[Test](http://jsperf.com/selector-test-100/2) based on @Felix test case.

Edit: so to enhance this answer. Based on the jQuery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#selector-context):

> By default, selectors perform their
>   searches within the DOM starting at
>   the **document root**. However, an
>   alternate context can be given for the
>   search by using the optional second
>   parameter to the $() function.

So when you provide a second parameter (a context), jQuery will search for that *element* first and then search within it, so it would be translated from:

```
$('.someElement', '#myId')
```

To:

```
$('#myId').find('.someElement')
```

Now the trick is, trying to find the closest container of your element that actually holds an ID and put it as *context*, since ID selection is the ***fastest***. Now you would say, why not then using the second already translated one, by I wouldn't actually care that much since the first is cleaner and it's not much slower:

```
                    $('.someElement', '#myId')                  $('#myId').find('.someElement')
Chrome 8.0.552              36,527                                      37,400
Firefox 3.6.13              17,632                                      19,155
```

Comment: Did not expect this result, this definitely is the correct answer! Thanks

Comment: @Michael: You are welcome, and please don't directly *tick* the answer button when your question is active, especially when having people like @Felix participating ;-)

Comment: :D I take this as a compliment :) Btw. interesting results. I thought `$('#myId .someElement')` would be faster in any case, as it can be directly translated to `querySelectorAll('$myId .someElement')`, but it seems that `$('#myId').find('.someElement')` is a lot faster. Wow.

Comment: Thx for the advice ifaour :) i was indeed to impulsive in ticking the answer ;)

Comment: @Felix Kling: As I said, I *guess* it works the same way CSS works..I just don't remember where I read that.

Comment: @ifaour: I found something: http://www.neeraj.name/2010/02/15/how-jquery-selects-elements-using-sizzle.html

Comment: `"Also the fewer the selectors the faster the selections will be"` - That's **not true**. String parsing is way faster than walking the DOM. If there are a lot of elements with class `.someElement` and `#myId` is up in the chain then the second one will be way more faster.

Comment: @galambalazs: my assumption is **NOT** based on the first example the OP used. Also, using too much selectors will add a lot of overhead! check this [out](http://jsperf.com/selector-test-100/8), also check my discussion with Felix about "right-to-left" selection.

Answer (score 5):

**Update 2:**

To sum up some other comments here. The answer is *it depends*.

jQuery's selector engine Sizzle evaluates the selector the same way CSS does: [from right to left](http://www.neeraj.name/2010/02/15/how-jquery-selects-elements-using-sizzle.html). So in general it is better to be very specific on the right side and less specific on the left side.

But it also depends on the structure of the HTML and how scattered the elements are that you want find.

So if you have

```
                         a
                         |
                        ...
                         |
                         b
                 -----------------
                 |               |
d d d c c c c c   c c c c c c c c   c c c c c c
```

then being more specific is faster `$('a b > c')`, because you are reducing the element set early with `b > c` and don't have to check the `a` inheritance for every `c`.

Whereas if you have

```
                         a
                         |
                        ...
                         |
                         b
                 -----------------
                 |               |
e e e e e e e e   d d c c c c c c   e e e e e e
```

then `$('a c')` would be faster, since the selector is simpler and testing `c` for being a child of `b` is redundant in this case (of course you could even do `$('c')`).

---

**Original answer**:

Regardless which one of them is faster, if you have to access an element over and over again, **store a reference to it**:

```
var $element = $('#myId .someElement');

$('some other selector').each(function() {
    // access $element here
});
```

---

[The first selector seems to be a bit faster](http://jsperf.com/selector-test-100) (in Chrome 8).

In newer browsers (that support `querySelectorAll`), the difference is probably not as big as in browsers that do not support it.

**Update:**

I think it mostly depends on how many built-in methods jQuery can use. So assuming `querySelector*` is not available, the first selector can be translated to

```
document.getElementById('myId')[0].getElementsByClassName('someElement')
```

For the second selector, jQuery would have to additionally check whether an element is indeed a child or not. I.e. there is some more processing involved.

Comment: Don't think this is an answer to the question.

Comment: @PeeHaa: Well, I see two parts in this question: 1) Which selector is faster? 2) For using it in an `each` loop. My answer is it does not matter which one is faster as you should not search for the same element over and over again :) It might not be a direct answer to the question but hopefully a good solution for the actual problem.

Comment: +1, not really the awnser i was looking for but you do point out an important part in code optimization, storing in vars is better then doing the call inside the loop over and over. (wasnt new to me btw ;) )

Comment: When using `a`,`b`,`c`, try to use them in sequence in your diagram.  The purpose of using them is so the brain does not have to work as hard to understand, when you arrange their hierarchy, it's actually complicating the interpretation.

Comment: @vol7ron: Good point... don't know why haven't done that from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

```
'#myid .myclass'
```

1) find all elements that have the class `myclass`
2) for each such element, go up its ancestor chain and stop if you get to the `#myid` ancestor. If there is no such ancestor, discard the element.

Now, it could very well be that browsers optimize this process, for example:

1) find the `#myid` element
2) find all elements that have the class `myclass` and that are descendants of the `#myid` element

---

```
table#myid > tbody > tr > td > div.mylcass
```

Note that prefixing the ID selector with a type selector has no effect, since IDs are unique in the document.

```
#myid > tbody > tr > td > div.mylcass
```

Prefixing a class selector with a type selector is performance-wise better. So, if you know the type of the element, you are encouraged to set it.

I'm not sure about those child selectors. I guess it should be faster if you use them. But how much faster? Possibly neglectable? Also, It looks ugly.

Consider this:

```
#myid td > div.myclass
```

If `#myid` is a table element, and you have no nested tables, then this selector should be as fast as your second selector. I'd use this one.

Comment: CSS selections work this way (right to left), but I don't think jQuery does.

Comment: @Šime - yeah *sometimes*. Not if the query is something which querySelectorAll can't handle, and not if the browser doesn't have that function. In this case, yes it would, but in general, no.

Comment: @nickf: Just found something interesting. Indeed Sizzle seems to evaluate the selector from right to left: http://www.neeraj.name/2010/02/15/how-jquery-selects-elements-using-sizzle.html

Comment: @Felix - thanks for the info - it's always interesting to learn something new. I wonder how the performance test would go if there were (say) 100 elements with `class="someElement"` in other places outside the table.

Comment: @nickf: Just made a test, the second is indeed faster then. But `$(something, context)` is still the fastest :http://jsperf.com/selector-test-100/5

Answer (score -1):

The second one will be faster, since it knows exactly what to look for at each step.

In this example:

```
$('table#myId > tbody > tr > td > div.someElement');
```

If there were no tbody, or no tr, or no td (etc), it could shortcut out of the search straight away. Also, every subsequent step will narrow down the search (eg: not searching inside the `<thead>`). Compare to this example:

```
$('#myId .someElement')
```

This would have to scan *every* sub-element of `#myId`.

---

*Edit*: As FelixKing pointed out, your first example `$('#myId .someElement')` is actually **faster**. Only marginally, but still, faster, so I thought I should respond. Using the child selector (`>`), as opposed to the descendant selector (a space) is the fastest traversal method, since the possible set of elements is much less. However, modern browsers have highly optimised built-in methods which jQuery can sometimes make use of, actually reducing the execution time. So, as seen in this particular case, the 'worse' one is actually better, since the browsers are better optimised for executing that particular query. In general however, the original point still stands, particularly if you're using something which couldn't possibly be optimised by browsers (custom selectors, for example).

Comment: Do you have any benchmark results for that or do you just assume? Because my tests say something different.

Comment: I totally agree with @Felix! I don't think the second is faster and indeed the tests resulted that it's not!...also I think (if not mistaking) it's the same approach as CSS selection (right to left)?

Comment: When it came down the logic i made the same conclusion, though @ifaour's test result point out something different

Comment: I just made a test with some nested divs and the first selector is still (if only slightly) faster: http://jsperf.com/selector-test-100/3

Comment: I agree, if you would implement both selectors with pure DOM traversal methods, then the second one would be faster. But there are optimized browser methods, and those have to be considered.

Comment: @Felix Kling, i guess I was taking the question as a generic "which style is faster" not "which out of these exact two queries is faster". *In general* using the child selectors is better, but obviously, these "optimisations" need to be checked (as you did with the performance tests).