# Best practice syntactically for multiple jQuery selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax, jquery-selectors

If I were to bind a click event to a lot of different selectors using jQuery like the following:

```
scrollToPoint('.main-nav a, .sub-nav a, .enquire-btn, #showcase-list a, #showcase-more-info a.back-btn')
```

What is the industry standard method to lay this out syntactically and is their an alternative approach?

Comment: Best approach is that you can have the same class for all the element that you want to select.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery same click event for multiple elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313373/jquery-same-click-event-for-multiple-elements)

Comment: @NiravGandhi That's no duplicate. The OP evidently knows *how* to target multiple elements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best Practices For Writing jQuery Selectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016542/best-practices-for-writing-jquery-selectors)

Comment: Clearly not a duplicate if you actually read my question. Thanks Aravind Sivam, you make a good point!

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the best approach IF YOU ARE SURE YOU WANT THAT MUCH SELECTORS:

```js
var selectors = [
    ".main-nav a",
    ".sub-nav a",
    ".all",
    ".other",
    ".selectors"
];

scrollToPoint(selectors.join(', '));

function scrollToPoint(sel){
  $('#selectors').text(sel);  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="selectors"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Selector optimization is less important than it used to be, as more browsers implement document.querySelectorAll() and the burden of selection shifts from jQuery to the browser.
Came from [jQuery's official site.](http://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/)